# How can I replace a color in an image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects

I want to replace the blue part of the image with red. I've tried this using a combination of the `Magic Wand` tool and the `Paint Bucket` but that doesn't work well.
Can somebody please help me out?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open the image in Photoshop
2. Double-click the layer `Background` to make a regular Layer out of it.
3. Go to `Image -> Adjustments -> Replace Color...`
4. Shift-click on the image to get the color range you want selected. You can adjust the `Fuzziness` parameter to your liking.
   [image]
5. Now choose the replacement color in the lower panel.
   [image]

Comment: This doesn't allow for re-editing should the user want to shift the tone a bit. I suggest using the adjustment layer outlined below...

Comment: It does work on a broader set of images, i.e. images that have other colors in it as well, instead of a b&w background. Each method has it's pro and cons.

Answer (score 5):

Create a new adjustment layer. Click the Icon the lower red arrow is pointing to! Then you can adjust the hue slider, (the top red arrow). Keep in mind this will not always be the case. It works in your scenario because blue is the only actual color and the rest is black and white.

There are also a number of other ways to accomplish this. However this is likely the most efficient in your case.

[image]

Comment: Agreed. And the adjustment layer allows for retouching if needed as opposed to set and "forget".